# how-to submit form with multiple groups of radio buttons?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, radio-button, form-submit

goal: post several groups of radio buttons to array (as a message, to database, etc.)

Hi there,
I was wondering how i can post my selections of several groups of radio buttons.
Here is the code:

```
    <body>

<form action="" method="post">
<select name="module 1">
<input type="radio" name="radioA" value="Radio 1">Radio 1
<input type="radio" name="radioA" value="Radio 2">Radio 2
<input type="radio" name="radioA" value="Radio 3">Radio 3
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</select>
<br>

<select name="module 2">
<input type="radio" name="radioB" value="Radio 21">Radio 21
<input type="radio" name="radioB" value="Radio 22">Radio 22
<input type="radio" name="radioB" value="Radio 23">Radio 23
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</select>
<br>

<select name="module 3">
<input type="radio" name="radioC" value="Radio 31">Radio 31
<input type="radio" name="radioC" value="Radio 32">Radio 32
<input type="radio" name="radioC" value="Radio 33">Radio 33
<input type="submit" name="submitC" value="Get Selected Values" />
</select>



<br>

</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(isset($_POST['radioA']))
{
echo "You have selected :".$_POST['radioA'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
}
}
?>


</body>
```

...But I can't make it display the list of my selections, but only one instructions, instead of 3x (one for each).

Long story short... How can I treat this as a 1 global set of 3 groups, having only 1 "submit" button to process all 3 groups at once?

Txs a lot, and have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the other two submit buttons and only display one. As long as it is inside the `<form>` it will submit all the radio button "groups" to the `$_POST`.

Also, remove the select tags as you are using them incorrectly. Only an option or optgroup should be nested inside a select element.

You will need to reference each one individually to see the selected response:

```
echo $_POST['radioA'];
echo $_POST['radioB'];
echo $_POST['radioC'];
```

Comment: txs dukedevil294. appreciated.